# SVN merge an older version with the head

Tags: svn, updates

I committed some code yesterday from "Workstation A" that caused some problems on our live server, so I rolled the live working copy back with the command 
`svn merge -r 652:651 ./`
All was good.

Today I'm on Workstation B, and I updated my local copy, made some changes to the code and committed again. However, the live server merged the changes and left the bits changed in 652 as they were.

So my question is - I've got a live website that I can't take down, and I need to update it to the very latest working copy (654 at the time of writing).

How do I do that?

Comment: I understand you did the reverse merge on the web server, but did not commit it? Then you should do the reverse merge on your workstation, commit it, revert the local changes on the web server and update it afterwards.

Comment: I've got the local copy exactly how I want it now - but the live copy refuses to play ball. Even though both are on the same revision (656 now) they have different code in =/

Comment: Check both working copies for local changes, i.e. your workstation and your server working directory. `svn status` should show nothing special.

Comment: I've got some files on the server that aren't checked in (I know about them) and a lot of files with "M" next to them, which I assume means "merged" - those are basically the ones that are "wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files with "M" on the server are modified. After checking them with

```
svn diff <filename>
```

you can revert them to the checked in state, which should be what you want:

```
svn revert <filename>
```

Comment: Hey, that seems to have worked! Thanks, man. Should I do a commit from the server now?

Comment: Hmm, isn't the state on the server now exactly the same as on your workstation and as it should be? In that case, you are already done. If you still need to undo the change 651->652, then you should repeat the reversed merge on your workstation, check the result and then commit that. Afterwards just update on the server.